# iOS const CGFloat error: linker command failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgfloat

I am trying to add constant `const CGFloat` in `Header.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#ifndef Sample_Header_h
#define Sample_Header_h

const CGFloat myCustomCoordinateY = 430.0f;

#endif
```

and I always  run into error:

```
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have googled this error, but, sadly I still haven't found a solution how to solve it. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is defined in a header file, When you import the header in more than one .m or .mm file, it will cause duplicate symbols error.

The solution is to declare it in your header file and assign a value to it in your .m or .mm file.

header file :

`extern const CGFloat myCustomCoordinateY ;`

.m file :

```
#import "Header.h"
const CGFloat myCustomCoordinateY = 430.0f ;
```